# Node.js in vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I wrote the below using VSCode and executed in the node.js terminal

```
let city = "Belgrade," 
let country = "Serbia" 
let location = city + ', ' + country
```

Apparently nothing works it goes like this.

[image: Terminal Display]

Comment: you've defined the variables, but not actually outputting anything so you can't see anything. Add a `console.log(location)` at the end if you want to see the value

Comment: Thank you very much ᔕᖺᘎᕊ  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like application worked perfectly well. You executed the node interpreter in the shell. So, the node engine took over, created 3 variables, then quit. Node does not output each statement it runs like a shell script does, so you would not see anything from the console unless you explicitly told it to do so. If you want to output to the console, you can simply use the `console.log()` function or one of its variants (you can find more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log). So try explicetely outputting your information to the console:

`let city = "Belgrade," 
let country = "Serbia" 
let location = city + ', ' + country
console.log(location)`

Answer (score 0):

Assignment only will not display the results. You need to print them out for displaying the values in the terminal.

```
console.log(city); 
console.log(country);
console.log(location);
```